# How to zip the output text file?

Tags: c++, c, winapi

My project require me to zip the output text file through a spawned process but i don,t have any clue how to do it. Here is my Source code for searching the file in the directory and writing the absolute file path  onto the text file.
//Everything is working all file . just want to know how to zip the output file ?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<windows.h>
#include<dir.h>
#include<string.h>
#define MAX 10000

//recursive search of directories
using namespace std;
class FileFinder
{
   int file_ctr;//How many files are there?
public:
    FileFinder(){file_ctr=0;}
    void getfile();
    void search(const char* path,const char* filename);
};

void FileFinder::getfile()
{
    char drive[10]={"G:\\"};//make it a 2D array and add all your Drives
    char filename[MAX];
    cout<<"Enter the File name\n";
    cin>>filename;
    FILE* fptr=fopen("test.txt","wt");//Delete the previous contents of File
    fclose(fptr);
    search(drive,filename);//loop through all drive[i]
    if(file_ctr==0)
        printf("\nNo File FOund!!!\n");
    else if(file_ctr==1)
    {
    char tmp[MAX];
    FILE* fptr=fopen("test.txt","rt");
    fgets(tmp,MAX,fptr);
    fclose(fptr);
    tmp[strlen(tmp)-1]=NULL;
    cout<<"\nFile found at Directory\t";
    printf("%s",tmp);
    }
    else
    {
       char tmp[MAX];
       FILE* fptr=fopen("test.txt","rt");
        cout<<"\n"<<file_ctr<<" Files Found!!\n";
       cout<<"\nFiles Found AT\n";
       for(int i=1;i<=file_ctr;i++)
       {
        fgets(tmp,MAX,fptr);
        tmp[strlen(tmp)-1]=NULL;
        cout<<"\n"<<i<<"\t"<<tmp;
        }
       fclose(fptr);
    }
    cout<<"\n\nPress any key to exit...";
    _getch( );
}
void FileFinder::search(const char* path,const char* filename)
{
    char tmp[MAX];
    WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;
    HANDLE hFind;
    strcpy(tmp,path);
    strcat(tmp,filename);
    hFind = FindFirstFile(tmp, &FindFileData);
    if(hFind != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
    while(hFind != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        char tmp1[MAX];
        FILE* fptr=fopen("test.txt","at");
        strcpy(tmp1,path);
        cout<<"\nSearching...  "<<tmp1;
        strcat(tmp1,FindFileData.cFileName);
        fputs(tmp1,fptr);
        fputs("\n",fptr);
        fclose(fptr);
        file_ctr++;
        if (!FindNextFile(hFind, &FindFileData))
        {
            FindClose(hFind);
            hFind = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
        }
    }
    }
    strcpy(tmp,path);
    strcat(tmp,"*.*");
    hFind = FindFirstFile(tmp, &FindFileData);
    while(hFind != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
       if(strcmp(FindFileData.cFileName,".")!=0 && strcmp(FindFileData.cFileName,"..")!=0 &&
                  FindFileData.dwFileAttributes==FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
       {
        char temp1[MAX];
        strcpy(temp1,path);
        strcat(temp1,FindFileData.cFileName);
        strcat(temp1,"\\");
        system("CLS");
        cout<<"\nSearching...  "<<temp1;
        search(temp1,filename);
       }
        if (!FindNextFile(hFind, &FindFileData))
        {
            FindClose(hFind);
            hFind = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    FileFinder f;
    f.getfile();
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Get a zip program, and execute it.

Comment: through a spawned process by mycode itself :)

Comment: It really depends on what platform you're on. You could use something like `fork` on unix, but I'm not sure what it would be on Windows. You could also use `system` calls, but a lot of people try to avoid using those. Depending on your use case, it may be simpler and easier to use a shell script of some sort.

Comment: Write yourself a Zip-Compression-Tool. Using [System.IO.Compression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.aspx) should make that pretty easy. You can create a .NET process the same way you create a process running native code.

Comment: @IInspectable Yeah, .NET is really applicable to standard C++.

Comment: some links for zip libraries http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7530/Zip-Utils-clean-elegant-simple-C-Win

Comment: @Captain: Where did you read the requirement, that the tool performing the zip-operation must be written in any particular language?

Comment: @IInspectable wouldn't it just be easier to use an extant zip tool? Why would we need yet another one?

Comment: @David: If you don't count *deployment*, then using a ready-made solution might be easier. If you plan to run the application(s) on multiple machines, reducing dependencies to 3rd party tools might be favorable.

Comment: @IInspectable Deployment code is the same here. That said, this is clearly a homework project. I doubt asker really needs to get into .net right now.